# Insertion sort code not working

Tags: c#, sorting, insertion-sort

Here is the method I have made for insertion sort:

```
private int i, j, temp;

public void InsertionSort(int[] a)
{
    for(i=0 ; i<a.Length-1 ; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1 ; j<1 ; j--)
        {
            if(a[j-1]>a[j])
            {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j - 1];
                a[j - 1] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
```

It is not sorting the array , when i stepped into the code i saw that the the code inside the inner for loop is not running and the code inside is being constantly surpassed.

for example take the array to be  `int[] arr = {7,2,3,6,} ;`

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you have `j=i+1 ; j < 1 .`... where `j< 1` is your condition... This can never be TRUE when `j=i+1` as your `i` starts at zero....I think you want `j>1` in your condition

Comment: I would take care with `i<a.Length-1` as I think you will need `i<a.Length `

Comment: No . You are getting it wrong . Basically i want the j loop to start from i+1 and end at 0 . Cause i am going from right to left .

Comment: Ummmm, despite your protest (lol), its not entering the second loop EVER with the current code.  Try j>1

Comment: Does it enter the second loop?  after the change I recommended?  with the data `int[] arr = {7,2,3,6} ;`.  If it does, I think that satisfied your question.  If this is homework, I won't finish your sort coding for you...

Comment: You're close. You actually want `j > 0` (or `j >= 1`).

Comment: Thanks @ChrisSinclair.... boundary issues :) The easiest to miss...I spotted the i loop one but not the one in my answer...  Murtaza - always look out for boundary issues (your start and your stop values).

Comment: @Grantly: If I had a nickel for every time I had an off by 1 error, I'd have 50 nickels... +/- 1 nickel.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Thankyou .  It works like a charm now . can you explain me a bit what was wrong in my j<1 ?

Comment: Speak it to yourself, and say 'only when j less than 1'... that should help make it clear why 'only when j is greater than zero' is your logical choice.  It is a condition, so it needs to be *true* to go through the for loop.

Comment: @MurtazaHasan - if you walk through your code, just in your head or on paper, and use your starting values for i and j, you will see how the logic of i<1 will not work (will not be *true*).  If you can write (here) what exactly you want the second loop to do - you will suddenly 'get' where your i<1 is going wrong.  As the process of writing it down, or talking it out are helpful.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks alot @Grantly . I have figured it out before even reading your comment . I cant believe , how could i commit such a huge blunder . Thanks mates .